# angular2js: Uncaught Reference Error: System is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to angular so please help. I am getting an error while trying to run a simple code with angular with angular ***ng-controller*** tag where I am displaying a variable in html being defined in a javascript file as:

```
var MainController = function($scope){
$scope.message = "harsh";
```

and displaying in html as in this:[html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJiVJ.png)

The error on chrome console is as:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined(anonymous function) @ angular2.js:3098

which points to some function in angular2js:

```
System.register("angular2/src/core/facade/lang", [], true, function(require, exports, module) {
```

I don't understand the problem. Is it related to the angular2.js which I included from angularjs.org?

Comment: `ng-controller` doesn't seem like something you'd use in Angular 2. I'd probably start here if I were you ~ https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: I guess this is from angular not angular 2....

Answer (score 10):

Try including the System JS file in your HTML.

```
<script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
```

Check this Github repo for any help: https://github.com/kensplanet/angularjs2-hello-world/blob/master/index.html

**Angular2 way of doing it**

Plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/36PZLTZ58bXmD4me0cpS?p=preview

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS2 Hello World Demo</title>

        <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
        <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <harsh></harsh>

    <script>
        System.import('harsh');
    </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

**harsh.js**

```
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") return Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    switch (arguments.length) {
        case 2: return decorators.reduceRight(function(o, d) { return (d && d(o)) || o; }, target);
        case 3: return decorators.reduceRight(function(o, d) { return (d && d(target, key)), void 0; }, void 0);
        case 4: return decorators.reduceRight(function(o, d) { return (d && d(target, key, o)) || o; }, desc);
    }
};
var angular2_1 = require('angular2/angular2');
var angularjs2Component = (function () {
    function angularjs2Component() {
        this.name = "Harsh";
    }
    angularjs2Component = __decorate([
        angular2_1.Component({
            selector: 'harsh'
        }),
        angular2_1.View({
            template: '<h1>Hello {{name}}<h1>'
        })
    ], angularjs2Component);
    return angularjs2Component;
})();
angular2_1.bootstrap(angularjs2Component);
```

**Output:**

> Hello Harsh

---

Comment: Thanx for help it did remove the error but the message is still not being displayed

Comment: In Angular2, ng-controller is not valid. Angular2 has no controllers. It has Components instead. So, your code won't work. Syntax is not similar to 1.x

Comment: @kensplanet what are these kind of error why is it happen

Comment: @flyingHawk I am not sure which error are you referring to. But if you mean the System.js error, then including the System.js file should fix the problem.

Comment: in my case the error dissappears but the problem does not.

Answer (score 2):

> I got the same issue in Angular 2.0 with TypeScript.

Im my issue I was requesting url with an extra slash '/' like 'http://localhost:3000/login/' (an extra slash after 'login')

Comment: This was exactly what I ran into. strange.

Answer (score 0):

Using `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2-all.umd.js` helped to remove this error. No external `system js` needed.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem kind of obvious, but make sure you've run:

```
npm install
```

to populate the *node_modules* directory in your app's root directory.  In particular you need:

```
node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem by following tutorial on PluralSight and using Plunker. I solved the issue by using this script

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" data-require="angular.js@*"></script>
```

instead of this:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-snapshot/angular2.js" data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

In case of you are using some Seed of AngularJS.

This issues can be if you will remove or not include something like this in `index.html`

```
  <!-- shims:js -->
  <!-- endinject -->
```

Sometimes developers who is not familiar with AngularJS 2 and particular seed project are thinking that they remove extra comments from HTML and even doesn't realize that it is `injection`.