# angular 2 install ReferenceError: System is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I try install angularjs and he give me this error:

```
ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

and this is my sources import:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS  -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- CORE ANGULARJS SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/angular2.min.js"></script>
```

I think is because missing js but I don't know what.
Can anyone help me with this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728887/angular2js-uncaught-reference-error-system-is-not-defined

Comment: the problem is it doesn't recognize the var angularjs. I tried:
var HelloAngular = function () {
  this.name = 'Angular 2.0';
};
HelloAngular.annotations = [
  new angular.ComponentAnnotation({
      selector: 'hello-angular'
  }),
  new angular.ViewAnnotation({
      template: '<H1>Hello {{name}}!</H1>You are awesome...'
  })
];
 from the angularjs web site and doesn't work