# Angular with TypeScript: ReferenceError: System is not defined System.config

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to install Angular 2 for TypeScript according to this tutorial: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

And I am getting this error:

> ReferenceError: System is not defined System.config

I don't know how this happens.

the folder structure:

```
project
|-index.hml
|-assets
    |-js
    |- jquery
    |-app
       |-app.component.js
       |-app.component.ts
       |-app.component.js.map
       |-main.js
       |-main.ts
       |-main.js.map
```

Comment: have you added `system.js`?

Comment: <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

Comment: I understand that. What you have done is, you have installed all packages npm and referencing them. I have shown you CDN/online references. Just try it once. Add all mentioned references to `index.html` and check if still error occurs!

Comment: now i get : Error: Unable to load script file:///D:/zontal-admin/app/main.js Error loading file:///D:/zontal-admin/app/main.js

Comment: 1) Do you have that file in that path? 2)Do you use local server to run the app?

Comment: you can also create a plunker if you can please do it. you will get immediate help.

Comment: the file is in D:\zontal-admin\assets\js\app, where i chage the path? 2) how do you mean local server is npm start?

Comment: ok i install de server using npm install http-server

Comment: Sorry now  I'm actually not able to help ahead as I'm not NPM guy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2js: Uncaught Reference Error: System is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728887/angular2js-uncaught-reference-error-system-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have SystemJS included into your HTML page. To make work your Angular2 application from your `node_modules` folder, you need at least:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script> <!---
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

And configure SystemJS to load your compiled TypeScript (actually JavaScript one with a `js` extension). Something like that:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    map: {
      app: 'assets/js/app'
    },
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

This configuration means that when you try to import some modules starting with `app/`, SystemJS will load corresponding JS file (compiled from TypeScript one). For example: `System.import('app/main');` will load the `app/main.js` file.

This means that you need to have compiled your TypeScript files before. When launching the `npm run start` command, the tsc compiler is automatically started in background and will compile TypeScript files into JS ones when changes will be detected. You can check that the compiler is actually started and you have the JS files created...

Comment: GIve me the same error if i put this:<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script> he give another error

Comment: he said:Error: Unable to load script file:///D:/zontal-admin/app/main.js Error loading file:///D:/zontal-admin/app/main.js because i have my app inside assets\js\app

Comment: You could try to add a `map` block in your SystemJS configuration. Something like that: `System.config({ map: { app: 'assets/js/app' }, packages: { ... } });`

Comment: it still don't work, i don't how change the directory

Comment: When is your HTML entry point file located? Could you also provide in your question the structure of your projects (folders, ts files and compiled js files)? Thanks!

Comment: I am using windows and obtain this error :Error: Access to restricted URI denied Error loading file:///D:/zontal-admin/assets/js/app/main, could someone help me?

Comment: Do you use a static web server like lite-server or http-server? This way you will be able to use the `http` protocol instead of the `file` one. I think that it's the reason of your error...

Comment: i add in the firs comment the file of sruture

Comment: I use the http-server and give me this error:
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/assets/js/app/main
 
404 Not Found

Comment: How do you import your `main` module: `System.import('app/main');`? In this case you need to have the `map` block in your SystemJS configuration. I updated this in my answer...

Comment: i use :System.import('assets/js/app/main')
How exacly i do the map?

Comment: In fact, `map` allows you to import like that: `System.import('app/main');`. If you import your way you need to define the `assets` package instead of the `app` one in the SystemJS configuration (no need of a map block in this case)...

Comment: how i define assets package?

Comment: this way: `System.config({ packages: {        
      assets: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
});`. The first level is important...

Comment: now i get  
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular2/core
 
404 Not Found and GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular2/platform/browser
 
404 Not Found

Comment: Do you include the angular2.dev.js file in your html file? This file provides the two modules...

Comment: <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script> this file?

Comment: you want the project to analyse?

Comment: Seems good. Is the file successfully loaded in the browser (see network tab of dev tools)? I mean do you the file on your local filesystem?

Comment: he only find the main and app.component and the css e js I already zip the project. how i out to downnload to you

Comment: You need to execute npm install to get the dependency. Otherwise this file i's available at https://code.angularjs.org

Comment: I have the project in this link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1a5enlei7irpf7a/AABorLrLaYvPKUN0MjSWp3Swa?dl=0

Comment: after the npm install i have 18 errors "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js" and the other two continues

Comment: now i get this errors:
 
404 Not Found
  16ms 
system.js (linha 4)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular2/platform/browser"
browser
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular2/platform/browser
 Error loading http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular2/platform/browser as "angular2/platform/browser" from http://127.0.0.1:8080/assets/js/app/main.js
 

system.js (linha 4)
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular2/core
 
404 Not Found
  71ms 
system.js (linha 4)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular2/core"

Comment: that is because angular2 is in the folder assets\js\app\node_modules\angular2\platform how do i change for this director?

Answer (score 2):

***index.html***

make sure to add following.

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>


<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
// error reason can be missing of this reference.


<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/http.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/router.dev.js"></script>
```

Comment: now i get : 
Error: Unable to load script file:///D:/zontal-admin/app/main.js
 Error loading file:///D:/zontal-admin/app/main.js

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate for [angular2js: Uncaught Reference Error: System is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728887/angular2js-uncaught-reference-error-system-is-not-defined/42532134#42532134)

In case of Angular2 Seed already implemented `injections` and required libs `loading` mechanism you should just use those methods.

In case of you are creating app from `scratch` you can include libs as you want as described above.