# System is not defined in angular2.0.0

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When i write `<base href="/">` in the index.html, then its shows error like `(index):21 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined`. 
And if i remove `<base href="/">` in index.html then 
it shows error like
 `core.umd.js:3462 EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:3:5 caused by: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.`
[image]

Console:
[image]

[image]

*Node Modules contains all that files*

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777642/angularjs-2-with-typescript-referenceerror-system-is-not-defined-system-config

Answer (score 1):

you are already loading  `system.js` from `node_modules` so you needn't import it from cdn link.

`<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script> //<-- comment this out.`

alternatively you should trying adding importing `APP_BASE_HREF` in root module instead of using `href`.

```
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [routing /* or RouterModule */], 
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }]
]);
```

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set) for more info.

Comment: if i do so, it shows `core.umd.js:3427 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'angular2'` and in address bar in shows `http://localhost/`  rather than `http://localhost/angular2`

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have not added this file in index.html

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
```

for reference have a look here
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't run npm install (assuming that you have package.json). 
All your errors are about not finding files in node_modules dir in your project.

For a sample project configuration see this sample project:
https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/tree/master/chapter2/angular-seed

Comment: complete work if i remove `<base href="/">`. and if i indclude `<base href="/">` than shows error.