# Angular2 two-way-binding NOT working

Tags: angularjs, angular

I can't figure out what will be the cause of this simple two-way binding not working in Angular 2, is it related to the configs, or?

```
import User from "../interfaces/user.interface.ts";
import {Component} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'application',
  template: '<h2>{{name}}</h2><input [(ngModel)]="name" /><input [(ngModel)]="name" />'
})
export class ApplicationComponent {
  public name:String = "test";
}
```

and here we have the main file:

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />

import 'reflect-metadata';

import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser"
import {ApplicationComponent} from './components/application.component';

bootstrap(ApplicationComponent);
```

When I start typing in the input field, the surrounding value between

### {{name}}

is not updated?

I can't continue playing with Angular 2, if this simple binding doesn't work and I don't believe this is related to the config files (webpack.config, tsconfig).

index.html file just in case!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>asd</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <application></application>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

**Any ideas to why two-way binding is not working, I appreciated :)**

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Plunker or JSFiddle, that might be helpful to understand what's wrong there.

I remove the following code from your example. And it works for me.
Here is my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jUG6P1pBNWHKssTgSinF?p=preview) with Angular2 2.0.0-beta.

```
import User from "../interfaces/user.interface.ts";
```

and

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

Comment: Didn't see `user.interface.ts` in plunker. If you comment out the same two lines I commented out in my plunker, does it work? Did you see any error in browser console?

Comment: I ended up upgradering my angular to the latest release, and then it worked, I don't know what was the cause. But now I just get "(index):13 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined"

Comment: Looks like your system.js is missing. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728887/angular2js-uncaught-reference-error-system-is-not-defined)